# Identify number of Duplicate elements in multi array

Tags: lightning, javascript

I had a multi array as follows

`0: {Name: "test1", Role: "Role1", Product: "Product4",Rate: 146,Rate_Override: 0}`

`1: {Name: "test2", Role: "Role1", Product: "Product1",Rate: 147,Rate_Override: 0}`

`2: {Name: "test3", Role: "Role1", Product: "Product1",Rate: 148,Rate_Override: 0}`

`3: {Name: "test4", Role: "Role2", Product: "Product1",Rate: 149,Rate_Override: 0}`

`4: {Name: "test5", Role: "Role3", Product: "Product2",Rate: 146,Rate_Override: 0}`

`5: {Name: "test6", Role: "Role1", Product: "Product1",Rate: 146,Rate_Override: 0}`

How can i get number of duplicate records that matches Role and Product ?

The combination of `Role1 and Product4 is 1`

The combination of `Role1 and Product1 is 3`

The combination of `Role2 and Product1 is 1`

The combination of `Role3 and Product2 is 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write code like this:

```
var values =
[{Name: "test1", Role: "Role1", Product: "Product4",Rate: 146,Rate_Override: 0},
{Name: "test2", Role: "Role1", Product: "Product1",Rate: 147,Rate_Override: 0},
{Name: "test3", Role: "Role1", Product: "Product1",Rate: 148,Rate_Override: 0},
{Name: "test4", Role: "Role2", Product: "Product1",Rate: 149,Rate_Override: 0},
{Name: "test5", Role: "Role3", Product: "Product2",Rate: 146,Rate_Override: 0},
{Name: "test6", Role: "Role1", Product: "Product1",Rate: 146,Rate_Override: 0}];

var dupes = {};
values.forEach(value => dupes[value.Role] = dupes[value.Role] || {});
values.forEach(value => dupes[value.Role][value.Product] = 1 + (dupes[value.Role][value.Product] || 0));
```

We build an object based on Role, then sub-objects based on Product (you can invert this if you desire). The output will look something like this:

```
{"Role1":
  {"Product4":1,
   "Product1":3},
 "Role2":
  {"Product1":1},
 "Role3":
  {"Product2":1}
}
```

Or you can even get the output like your question:

```
Object.keys(dupes).forEach(role =>
    Object.keys(dupes[role]).forEach(product =>
        console.log("Role "+role+" and "+product+" has "+dupes[role][product]+" values.")
    )
);
```

Output:

```
Role Role1 and Product4 has 1 values.
Role Role1 and Product1 has 3 values.
Role Role2 and Product1 has 1 values.
Role Role3 and Product2 has 1 values.
```